How to find out keybinding for command starting with particular words in emacs?
I would like to find a way in Emacs to display only those commands that already have key bindings, based on the words I type after M-x. Ideally, this should leverage describe-keymap for the current mode and work effectively with ivy-mode. For example, if I type M-x org-table, instead of listing all possible completions, it should show only the commands that have existing key bindings. This functionality could be integrated with counsel-M-x and similar tools.
I tried M-x with ivy-mode on, and it gives me completion for all the commands rather than just one with key-bindings.

Figuring out if the command is bound to a key sequence is complicated. See help-fns--key-bindings in help-fns.el.

See also the section on Scanning Keymaps in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.
